# TCL: append several key-value pairs to dict at once

Tags: tcl

I'd like to add multiple key-value pairs to a `dict`.

I tried append, lappend and `set` but the key-value pairs get appended as one big string.

Here's the code:

```
set myNewDict [dict lappend $myOldDict \
"field one" "VALUE1" \
"field two" "VALUE2" \
"field three" "VALUE3" \
"field four" "VALUE4"

]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like `dict merge`:

```
% set d [dict create 1 foo 2 bar]
1 foo 2 bar
% set d [dict merge $d [dict create \
2 baz \
3 example \
4 stuff]]
1 foo 2 baz 3 example 4 stuff
```

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't provide that natively. However, the [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm) command is implemented as an [ensemble](http://wiki.tcl.tk/13310) and can be extended. Some examples are on the [dicttools](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17686) wiki page but in this case the following defines a suitable procedure then adds it to the dict ensemble so that you can call it as a single command.

```
proc ::tcl::dict::append2 {dictVarName args} {
    upvar 1 d $dictVarName
    foreach {k v} $args {
        dict append d $k $v
    }
}
namespace ensemble configure dict -map \
    [linsert [namespace ensemble configure dict -map] end \
    append2 ::tcl::dict::append2]
```

Example use:

```
% set d [dict create]
% set d
% dict append2 d a 1 b 2 c 3
% set d
a 1 b 2 c 3
```

Comment: Sometimes you have to make a judgement call about what functionality to provide and what to omit…

Comment: What about `dict merge`?

Comment: I used @JohannesKuhn solution because it was simpler. But thanks for showing, how I could extend the functionality!

Comment: And why do you treat the ensemble map as a list (`lappend`)  and not as dict? `namespace ensemble configure dict -map [dict merge [namespace ensemble configure dict -map] {append2 ::tcl::dict::append2}]`

Comment: Because I'm much more used to processing things in tcl using lists. However, given the namespace command here returns a dict object (as checked using tcl::unsupported::representation) `dict merge` is probably slightly more efficient. It won't make much difference though really.